# How to save the page object for later use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My puppeteer is going to have multiple user access it, but after they did or before they start I want to track which page they opened if they want to do more action or not. Close the page in 30 min after if any action not perform.

Is there any page ID or something I can use, I saw there's `browser.pages` to get the index, but don't know how to utilize this function.

my application is a REST server where a user will post a request and puppeteer will do some task.

Comment: Do you want to give other users the option to connect from their puppeteer script to your pool of browser instances or do you want to execute one task per user request (like making a screenshot)? What is unclear about [browser.pages](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserpages)?

Comment: Just execute one task, 1st task is register course, 2nd task(optional and only last 30min) to delete current registration. For browser.page I haven't looked very into it just know there is method exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concept

When a request comes in, a function is called which creates a page for a userid and stores that page in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for later use. Then when the second request hits, you take the existing page from the Map, perform the "finishing" task and close the page afterwards.

### Sample code

For simplicity, this sample uses [express](http://expressjs.com). The code starts a server and registers two functions:

- `/open?userid=XXX` will call the starting task for the given userid
- `/close?userid=XXX` will call the finishing task for the given userid

This is a minimal example without error handling or edge cases (like what happens if you call the open function twice without calling close).

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// contains the open pages (per userid)
const openPages = new Map();

// setup task, creates page
async function openTask(userid, browser) {
    // create page and save in our map
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    openPages.set(userid, page);

    // execute start task on page
    await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
    // ...

    // always call closeTask after 30min
    setTimeout(() => closeTask(userid), 30 * 60 * 1000);
}

// end task, closes page
async function closeTask(userid) {
    const page = openPages.get(userid);
    if (!page) {
        return;
    }

    // execute end task on page and close page after that
    // ...
    await page.close();
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    // Called like this: /open?userid=123
    app.get('/open', async function (req, res) {
        const userid = req.query.userid;
        await openTask(userid, browser);
        res.end(`open finished for userid ${userid}`);
    });

    // Called like this: /close?userid=123
    app.get('/close', async function (req, res) {
        const userid = req.query.userid;
        await closeTask(userid, browser);
        res.end(`close finished for userid ${userid}`);
    });

    app.listen(3000);
})();
```

---

#### Pages, contexts, browsers

Depending on your task, you should think about whether it makes more sense to use [browsers](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browser) or [contexts](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext) instead of pages. This would make the tasks more independent from each other, meaning if one browser crashes, it would not effect any of the other tasks. In addition, using pages will also make all tasks share cookies.

Comment: yes I found save browser was better choice than save the page